# path to temp directory in cpan

Tags: windows, perl, cpan, strawberry-perl, home-directory

I'm trying to install Tk module for perl in windows with cpan.
Problem is:

```
Checking if you have Test::More 0 ... Yes (0.98)
Checking if you have Encode 0 ... Yes (2.44)
Building Tk-804.03 ... dmake.exe:  Error: -- `C:\Documents' not found, and can't
 be made
FAIL
! Installing Tk failed. See C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\.cpanm\build.log for
 details.
```

In build.log no additional info.

How to change path to ".cpanm" directory to any other without spaces? 
Default value is "~/.cpam" and i did not found way to change it.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is to use

```
C:\some\dir> set HOME=G:\some\directory\with\no\spaces
```

in the cmd.exe window in which you are using. That would only change the setting in that window, and would not affect anything else.

In fact, my permanent environment on my XP laptop contains a similar `HOME` setting: `E:\Home\username`, because I don't like dealing with this kind of stuff.

Yes, our tools ought to be able to handle paths with spaces in them, but such is the injustice of life.